# AppFabric Server Caching Service Configuration Store Error

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I have installed AppFabric in my Windows 8.1 Pro machine and I'm facing problems while configuring it.

I am getting the below error when I clicked on "Configure" button inside "Caching Service" section of "AppFabric Server Configuration Wizard".

I have googled with the error text, but could not find useful information.

Can anybody please tell what I am missing!

[image: AppFabric Servre Caching Service Configuration Store Error]

Answer (score 0):

See this article - [Walkthrough: Deploying Windows Server AppFabric in a Workgroup Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718166%28v=azure.10%29.aspx):

> This section describes how to install and configure Windows Server
>   AppFabric on multiple computers in a workgroup environment. In this
>   scenario, you will configure the AppFabric Hosting Services feature to
>   use SQL Server data stores, and configure the AppFabric Caching
>   Services feature to use an XML file in a shared file store for
>   configuration information. **In a workgroup environment, a SQL Server
>   database is not supported for configuration data for the Caching
>   Services feature, so you must use a shared file store.**

You are attempting to use a Sql Server database for the Caching Services feature in a workgroup environment: you need to use a shared file store, which means setting up a file share with the cache config in an XML file. The article goes into detail about how to do that.